# Clicking Submit button on a web page with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web, automation

I'm using IE version 9 and trying to click "submit" button using VBA. I've tried many ways but getting no luck.

Can anyone please help? below is the element code of button. Please note that "on click" doesn't have space in real codes.

Button code :

```
<input type = submit value = " Submit " on click= "return submitDWAC(this.form)">
```

I've already tried below, but they are not working.

```
.Document.getelementbytagname("Submit").Click   

.Document.all("Submit").click

Sendkey {ENTER}, TRUE
```

Please assist.....

Answer (score 1):

The tag name is `<input` not `submit` but an easier way to do this is the use the form.submit() method:

```
.document.forms(0).submit
```

If there is only one form on the page then this should do the trick, otherwise you will need to enumerate through the form objects and test each one to see which one you want to submit.

Comment: so I have two buttons. One is SUBMIT and other one is RESET I'm putting their codes. It would be great if you can take a look and advise.

`<input type = submit value = " Submit " onClick = "return submitDWAC(this.form)">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset"  value=" Reset ">`

Comment: I just did take a look and advise - forget about the button, target the form instead and invoke the `.submit` method which is much easier and faster.

Comment: That makes no sense, I don't know what you are asking. Just replace what you have with the line that I have supplied in my answer.

Comment: I'll give it a try with below code in the morning

`.document.forms(0).submit`

Answer (score 1):

For starters `.getelementbytagname`  does not exist so this:

```
.Document.getelementbytagname("Submit").Click
```

would fail. The method is `.getElementsByTagName`. There is a `"s"` after element, indicating that a collection of elements is returned.

The HTML you show is of an `input` tag as mentioned in the other answer. Submitting the form is a good way to go, or you can target that `input` tag and by its `type` attribute, using a CSS selector, and go with:

```
.document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").Click
```